# what to do about paint peeling on lever door knobs?

Tags: doors

We are in a medical office and the paint quickly peels off the handles on all of the doors. I'm guessing it is because everyone uses alcohol based hand sanitizers before and after they enter the rooms.

Anyway, it leaves us with little flecks of paint on our hands.

Is there a sealant that we can apply to the handles so that they won't peel?

A handle that won't peel or be affected? Stainless?

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a medical office and is not _home_ improvement.

Comment: I would try an acrylic clear coat after painting, aka high-quality clear spray paint. It should be impervious to alcohol and it's non-toxic and it forms a strong protective bond as the paint molecules fuse into essentially a single molecule.

Comment: What paint? Please revise your post to be more clear about the coating on your hardware and whether it was there from the factory.

Comment: The door handles, @dandavis, should come from the factory with a pretty long-wearing coating on them. Shouldn't require anything else. Of course, since these have now been painted, and if the paint is chemically stripped, something may need to be applied. Seems the easiest thing would be to just finish scraping the paint off by hand (since it's coming off so nicely as it is), and leave them with their factory finish as they should have been in the first place.

Comment: Acrylic paint is particularly vulnerable to alcohol. instead use use an industrial coating like power-coat or 2-pack, or use handles with a metallic finish  like brass or stainless-steel, (brass contains lots of copper which makes it it's inherently anti-microbial, which is probably good in a medial setting)

Comment: Of note, this is also a problem in cars where the alcohol in hand lotions tends to wear the black paint off of controls leaving behind the translucent plastic that _used_ to indicate what the button was for (when the button was backlit). I ran into significant issues with this when shopping for used VWs (in particular) for my son.

Answer (score 7):

There is a reason, which you have discovered, why door handles (whether round doorknobs or levers) are usually *not* painted. The usual solution is bare metal - typically brass or stainless steel. Even without alcohol, cleansers, etc. paint will either rub off or get very dirty from oil and dirt in hands.

Comment: Gotta agree!  Strip them to bare metal and wipe them down with sanitizer a couple of times a day.

Answer (score -2):

Hire a Handyman to strip the paint off all the handles that are a problem.

Comment: This is more of a comment level than answer level, but it seems perfectly valid (especially since this really isn't a DIY question, since it's about a commercial establishment). Not the highest quality answer ever written here, but I'm not sure it deserves the DVs.

Comment: Thank You FM. This was asked by those in a profession, regarding their office, rather than someone doing work on a home. Most professionals need direction as to whom may be able to correct the problem. Thus my answer.

Comment: Most medical offices (I work for a hospital system), are in leased space, and you call building maintenance for these things, you don't call in a handyman on your own...

Comment: ...Ah yes...but we don't know that the spaced is leased or not.  and if it is they could call their maintenance. However the OP posted here, so all is speculation.